# Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string. When using SwiftUI specifically

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a node/express backend that I am accessing via SwiftUI. The express backend makes some calls to a firestore DB I have and works fine when testing with CURL, but for some reason returns this error whenever I call from the SwiftUI frontend.

`Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.`

Even when hard coding the document to make sure the string is not empty I get the error when using the emulator in xcode but not when doing a CURL request.

This is the express code:

```
app.get('/users/getUserEmail/:email', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("IN GET USER EMAIL")
  // const { email } = req.params;
  const email = 'test'
  console.log(email)
  console.log(typeof email)

  const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(`${email}`);

  console.log({userRef: userRef._path})

  const userData = await userRef.get();

  console.log('DOC HAS BEEN AWAITED')

  if (!userData.exists) {
    return res.status(200).send({existing: false});
  }

  res.status(200).send({existing: true});
})
```

Even when not hard coding, the email log is always populated and it is always a string

This is the SwiftUI code:

```
class DatabaseService: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = DatabaseService()
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    private let baseURL = "http://localhost:8383"

    func checkForUnusedEmail(email: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: baseURL + "/users/getUserEmail/\(email)")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .tryMap { (data, response) in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                    dump(response)
                    throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
                }
                return (data)
            }
            .decode(type: UnusedEmailResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completionEvent in
                switch completionEvent {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error:", error.localizedDescription)
                    completion(.failure(error))
                case .finished:
                    print("Unused Email request finished")
                }
            }, receiveValue: { response in
                return completion(.success(response.existing))
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

}
```

I tried hard coding the values to make sure they were always strings and that still caused the error but only specifically when trying from the SwiftUI frontend. It should return with a response from the Firestore database.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything unique to SwiftUI here -- I assume you mean that the problem is when using _Swift_. If you can get it to work in a Swift context but not SwiftUI, you should show the differences between the code that works and the code that doesn't.

Comment: Observations: the Swift code you show is from the dark ages, try using the more modern Swift async/await
 concurrency, it's just a one liner. `let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)`. Also note Apple requires `https` unless you have set your NSAppTransportSecurity to accept `http`.